# Is it possible to call a PageReference method from inside the controller (w/o user interaction)?

Tags: apex, controller-extension

I'm wondering if it's possible to call a PageReference method in a controller without the user having to click on any vf page buttons. For example, I have the following condition...(see below)...and I want to call the customSave() method based on a boolean statement, but it's not working.

```
    public String getJSONString(){
        String fault = 'fault';
        if(this.jsonString.containsNone(fault))
        {
            customSave();
        }
        return.this.jsonString;
    }

    public PageReference customSave(){
       //do some stuff
       stdCtrl.save();

       PageReference redirectPage = new PageReference('apex/newpage');
       redirectPage.setRedirect(true);
       return redirectPage;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. Functions can generally be called from any other function. However, I'm under the impression that you have your jsonString variable defined as:

```
public String jsonString { get; set; }
```

Since you're also using `getJsonString()` as a function, this will shadow (read: override) the public getter and setter on the variable itself; the controller won't be able to see the value you're assigning, as it will effectively be read-only. I'm not sure why you're not getting a compilation error, but you should be able to fix your problem by adding the following code:

```
public void setJsonString(String value) {
    jsonString = value;
}
```

Please note, however, that DML operations during the getter-setter phase are dangerous (and usually not allowed), which is probably why you're not seeing the expected results. Instead, consider calling an action, and then performing your save during the action method:

```
public void doAction() {
    if(jsonString != null && !jsonString.contains('fault')) {
        customSave();
    }
}
```

Note that it isn't necessary to check the return value, but any DML exceptions in your code should be handled appropriately (e.g. if stdCtrl.save() returns a null page reference, display an error).